# Using setkeycodes to map pressed and released to different "keys"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have a [keyboard](http://www.a4tech.com/product.asp?cid=1&scid=1&id=206) that has a scroll wheel, but it doesn't work on Ubuntu and `xev` command doesn't show anything when moving it. But with the `dmesg` command I found this:

When moving the scroll wheel up:

```
atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0x8b on isa0060/serio0).
atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e00b <keycode>' to make it known.
```

When moving the scroll wheel down:

```
atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x8b on isa0060/serio0).
atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e00b <keycode>' to make it known.
```

It seems to be the same key but the pressed/released change if moving it up/down.

`xmodmap -pke | grep croll` shows:

```
keycode  78 = Scroll_Lock NoSymbol Scroll_Lock
keycode 185 = XF86ScrollUp NoSymbol XF86ScrollUp
keycode 186 = XF86ScrollDown NoSymbol XF86ScrollDown
```

**How do I configure it so when "pressed" is keycode 185 and when "released" is keycode 186?**

Comment: What was the `dmesg` command you used? I try to find out something else here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450066/how-can-i-disable-the-touchpad-on-yoga-2-pro-with-the-hotkey-and-in-tablet-mode

Answer (score 3):

you should use `setkeycodes` to assign a keycode.

http://www.jveweb.net/en/archives/2011/01/configure-unrecognized-keys-in-linux.html

the scan code of the keys were unrecognized, this is, no key code was found to be associated with the scan code, the important value here appears right next to the setkeycodes command. 
So You have to define **e00b**

find out an unused keycode with

```
xmodmap -pke | less
```

and then assign a key code with the command

```
setkeycodes
```